# When does writing isEqual make sense in Swift?

Tags: cocoa, swift, equality

"Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective C" makes it pretty clear you should define isEquals for things that inherit from NSObject, but following that, I'm not sure when I need to write it. It says:

“Because you can pass Swift objects (including ones not derived from NSObject) to Objective-C APIs, you should implement the isEqual: method for these classes if you want the Objective-C APIs to compare the contents of the objects rather than their identities.”

But, how can we know when the Cocoa APIs are going to be using the isEquals method?

Comment: The Cocoa API will always use the isEqual method when comparing generics. Ex: Comparing `NSString` subclass to `id` will use isEqual.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you quoted doesn't suggest you should try guessing whether or not the Cocoa API will use `isEqual:` or not.  The documentation you quoted suggested that any time you're going to pass an object to an Objective-C API, it should implement this method.

So, for ANY object you pass to ANY Cocoa API, you should implement the `isEqual:` method just in case the Cocoa API you're using makes use of this method.

Comment: If we could somehow guarantee that there would only ever be one instance with a certain set of data, for example, wouldn't we want to not implement it?

Comment: From the text you quoted, it sounds like if there is no `isEqual:`, the identities will be compared (their memory location), so you wouldn't necessarily have to implement it, but for completeness, I'd implement it just as a `===` comparison so we make it explicitly clear that this is what we're intending to do.